# How to import image link data to excel row

Tags: wordpress, excel, woocommerce

i have a big excel file with more than 1000 rows, each row is a product with it's SKU number and other product details.
I have all product images in a folder on the computer, each image name is the SKU number of the product.
I need to upload everything in woocommerce, my problem is that images are not associated to the products inside the excel file. Is there a way to dynamically/batch import the image name (with the .jpg suffix) to each row of the excel file?

Hope i was clear enough....

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: @pnuts Thanks! Sure that is what is more logical to do. Could you please explain me better how do i do this in the excel file?  Guess i can just duplicate the SKU column, but how do I append the .jpg suffix automatically to elements in the new column?

Comment: @pnuts
the [wordpress] tag just because i am going to import the excel (cvs) file in wordpress...by the way, maybe just appending the .jpg suffix is not enough, i guess i need to upload all images before importing the cvs file. Do i need to specify the exact path of the images in the column for each product?

Comment: Great, thank you!!!Sorry, other question...how do i batch this for each row of the excel file (more than 1000....)?

Comment: Guess i found it, thank you again!
=A1:A1000&".jpg"